# Unable to connect Flask app to MySQL database in Docker-compose setup

Tags: docker, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm encountering an issue with connecting my Flask app to a MySQL database in a Docker-compose setup. The Flask app is hosted in a container, and I have two MySQL containers (`db` and `warehouse_db`). While I can successfully connect to the db database, I'm facing difficulties connecting to the warehouse_db.

**DETAILS**

Docker-compose.yml:

Here is a snippet of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    links:
      - db
      - warehouse_db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - warehouse_db
    networks:
      - brewandbrain_network
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: "512M"

  db:
    # ... (details for db service)

  warehouse_db:
    # ... (details for warehouse_db service)
networks:
  brewandbrain_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Error Message:
When I try to run the Flask app, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "Unable to connect to the warehouse database"
}
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- I've verified that the warehouse_db service is running using docker-compose ps.
- Checked the MySQL server logs for the warehouse_db service, but no apparent issues.
- Tested connecting to the warehouse_db service directly from the app container using docker-compose exec app mysql -h warehouse_db -uroot -p, and the connection is successful.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs, maybe with a more detailed exception?  In the server, how have you configured the database information?  Does the database container have the same `networks:` block?

Comment: ([Compose file version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) doesn't support a `deploy:` keyword.  `links:` are obsolete and can be safely removed.  You should be able to delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file; Compose will create a network named `default` and attach all of the containers to it.)